# Installing Pytorch-Geometric issues

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I'm new to Pytorch. Pytorch was working fine but when I installed Pytorch-geometric, I get this error. Not sure how to resolve

```
ImportError: libcupti.so.11.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Think I read something like adding an export to an LD Library or something, but not sure as I don't really understand it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you give us more detailed information on your python, PyTorch, nvcc, and CUDA versions?

Comment: You might want to look at the directory and see if `libcupti.so.11.2` is missing but the other `libcupti.so.11.*` is present.